# remove selected firebase data according to condition onload

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete data that will meet the condition I set. That is, once the 'Deadline' passed today's date, they must be deleted.

This is my realtime database
[image]

This my code to get the current date and compare it to the deadlines in the db

```
// get today's date
let today = new Date();
let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
let yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
let now = today.toString();

function deadlineLimit(){

    const q = query(ref(db, "subjects/MMW/"));

    get(q).then((snapshot)=>{

        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var deadlines = childSnapshot.val();
            var dbDates = deadlines["Deadline"];

            // if deadlines in database < date today
            if (dbDates < today){
                let expiredDeadline = childSnapshot.val().Deadline;
                console.log(expiredDeadline + " Must be removed");          // Must be deleted

                // CODE HERE to remove all data that met the condition
            }
        })
    });
}

deadlineLimit();    // call this function
```

I am able to get the deadlines past todays date, but how can i delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`remove()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#remove) function to delete those nodes as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data):

```
get(q).then(async (snapshot) => {
  const deletePromises = [];

  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    var deadlines = childSnapshot.val();
    var dbDates = deadlines["Deadline"];

    if (dbDates < today) {
      // push to promises array
      deletePromises.push(remove(childSnapshot.ref))
    }
  })
  
  await Promise.all(deletePromises);
  
  console.log("Data deleted")
});
```